# Whether we can create an App Extension for WatchKit(WatchOS 2) App similar to that of iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode7, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm developing an WatchKit App (using WatchOS 2). 
I have one query whether we can create an App Entension for WatchKit App similar to that of iOS, so that other WatchKit App(host app) can use this extension for sharing purpose (may be a text or an image or a link).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. You want to know if the  watch app extension can be shared between the phone and the watch?

Comment: @KyleRedfearn : Actually the scenario is like can some other watchKit app can share its data (text, image, link etc.) in my watchKit app(if for ex. my app is social networking app). Synonymous to that of using share sheet in iOS to share our content to some other iOS App.

Comment: @KyleRedfearn: With some RnD I actually came to conclusion that its not possible in watchKit right now(watchOS 2.0). As in iOS we have to create 'Share Extension' to accomplish this task, but watchKit itself is an extension of iOS app. So can't have extension for extension itself. Also we don't have Sharesheet kind of thing in watchKit using which we can share our content to another app.

Comment: @Mahesh The only possible way to work around this is to use a back-end. The flow will be like that: the host app "asks" a backend to share some stuff using another iPhone. Another iPhone then receives a notification from the backend with all the data to share and sends data to its related watchkit app. (for the end user it will look as if one watchkit app shared data with another). Did I understand it correctly: this is a flow you want to acieve?